# Mockito mock is not properly matching arguments (?)

Tags: spring, mockito, stubbing

I'm trying to stub one method in service layer for testing another object:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
class WorkreportCrudFacadeTest {

  private static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(WorkreportCrudFacadeTest.class);

  @Test
  public void detailTest() {

    final AccessRightsService ars = Mockito.mock(AccessRightsService.class);
    final SystemPriceSettingService spss = Mockito.mock(SystemPriceSettingService.class);
    final WorkreportActivityRepository wrar = Mockito.mock(WorkreportActivityRepository.class);
    final WorkreportRepository wrr = Mockito.mock(WorkreportRepository.class);
    final DomainObjectTools dot = Mockito.mock(DomainObjectTools.class);
    final ApplicationEventPublisher aep = Mockito.mock(ApplicationEventPublisher.class);

    Mockito.when(ars.hasEmployeeRightsToWorkReport(
        ArgumentMatchers.any(Employee.class), ArgumentMatchers.any(Workreport.class)
        )
    ).thenReturn(true);

    final WorkreportCrudFacade s = new WorkreportCrudFacade(ars, spss, wrar, wrr, dot, aep);

    final EmployeeId employeeId = new EmployeeId(154149756298300L);
    final WorkreportId workreportId = new WorkreportId(154149757395700L);

    final Workreport detail = s.detail(workreportId, employeeId);

    LOGGER.debug("Detail: {}", detail);

  }

}
```

and method that invokes tested method:

```
  public Workreport detail(final WorkreportId workreportId, final EmployeeId employeeId) {

    final Workreport workreport = domainObjectTools.getWorkreportOrThrowNotFoundException(workreportId);
    final Employee viewer = domainObjectTools.getEmployeeOrThrowNotFoundException(employeeId);

    boolean hasRights = accessRightsService.hasEmployeeRightsToWorkReport(viewer, workreport);

    LOGGER.debug("Has rights: {}", hasRights);

    if (!hasRights) {
      throw new ForbiddenException();
    }

    return workreport;

  }
```

but when I call tested method `hasEmployeeAccessToWorkReport` on `WorkreportCrudFacade` instance, the method is not properly stubbed (it should return `true`, but returns `false`).

I'm sure it'll be some detail but I'm not able to find out what is wrong - probably something in argument matcher, but not sure.

I'm using Mockito 2.22.0.

Comment: Is `ars` a mock and is that method actually called with those arguments? The default behavior is to return `false` hence it appears as if you aren't using what you think you are using.

Comment: I added a mock creation into question. Is it correct?

Comment: The creation seems ok, but that still doesn't mean it is actually being used. Post the full test (at least the method and needed class level stuff).

Comment: I added full test source.

Comment: Looks like it should be called with a `WorkreportId` instead of a `Workreport`. What is the `s.detail` method actually doing? Also why all the annotations? Those add nothing at all (apart from the `@RunWith` )...

Comment: No, it's ok. I added full source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Citing from [ArgumentMatchers javadoc](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.23.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html):

> Since Mockito any(Class) and anyInt family matchers perform a type check, thus they won't match null arguments. Instead use the isNull matcher.

I think that the following happens here: Your `DomainObjectTools` is an empty mock (not stubbed) and thus it returns null `Workreport` and null `Employee`. It results in calling `accessRightsService.hasEmployeeRightsToWorkReport(null,null)`. The `null` values are not matched by `ArgumentMatchers.any(Class)`.

Comment: Thank you mockk also does the same, my test was failing due to null arguments